# How to change a label from scrollView movement in Xcode 4.6

Tags: ios, xcode4.6

I have a project which contains a scrollView with some imageViews inside it. Each imageView has a simple image with a colour and my scrollView moves only vertically. When I run my project, the scrollView appears with the same image frame like it should, and change the image when I scroll up or down. Now I need to associate a number to each coloured image that appears as the scroll movement occurs.
How can I do this?

Ps: I only used the storyboard, but no code.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you saying you want a number to appear over each of the `UIImageView`s? And the numbers scroll with the image views? If so, I suggest adding a `UILabel` on top of each of the image views. Set the `text` property of the `UILabel` to the desired number. If the number is fixed and does not need to change, you can do all that in your storyboard.

Comment: The problem is that I need this number in a specific label, and this label need to stay below UIImageView. So I need change just one label that isn't in front of UIImageView.